# UINavigation button change

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 view controllers, 2 of them with some data that i display in the third controller..
I want to change the third controller navigation button according to from which controller i read the data..

Example: If i pressed on row in controller 1, i want the button on controller 3 to be "edit"
and if i pressed on a row in controller 2 i want the button on controller 3 to disappear..

How can i do so?

I am pretty new to iOS development so an example with some explanation would be great..
thank you!

Comment: can u elaborate in detail?

Comment: hi u can read this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies/  and then ask what is your exact question , i feel your question was little bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all pushed viewControllers with the help of this single line.

```
navigatonController.viewControllers
```

From this array of view controllers,

if `Vc1` is pushed, then check the pushed viewcontroller.

```
if([Vc1 isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 classs]]) {

     // display your button.

}
else ([Vc2 isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]){

    //hide your button.

}
```

Comment: what should i do with this line? 
navigatonController.viewControllers

and should i pass instead of "VC1" "VC2"?

Answer (score 0):

For each of the first two view controllers, set the `title` property of the controller's navigation item to the title that you want displayed in the back button. The navigation controller will use that to set the back button title in the third view controller.

Comment: I know that.. When I said "edit" I ment to edit button.. ( just for example, I don't really need it). Please read my question again, I would be greatful if you could answer..